# ArrayFind() returning false when it should return an index value!

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, struct, coldfusion-9

Why does arrayFindNoCase() return false? Shouldn't it return 2?

```
local.data =
[
   {
      name = "foo",
      value = 5
   },
   {
      name = "bar",
      value = 6
   }
];

local.key = arrayFindNoCase(data, { value = 6 });
```

Comment: I would only expect 2 when searching for the whole element ie `{ name="bar", value = 6 }` .

Comment: @Leigh, I had no idea that was the case. Do I have any options if I'm only looking for partial matches?

Comment: @Leigh, that's what I ended up doing. The thing is, the function was already inside a loop. So I had to do a nested loop which was a bit complicated. I got it figured out. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think looping is as good as it gets .. unless you are going to refactor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really, since { value = 6 } != { name = "bar", value = 6 }

Comment: if it's absolutely necessary to only use partial matches, what are my options?

Comment: Do it the old fashioned way? ie Loop and check each element.

Comment: Try ArrayContains http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WS2EF4F7C2-F41D-42fe-940D-B7C0212FF3D9.html

Comment: Unfortunately I do not think arrayContains does partial matches either.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do partial matches... If you had searched as below, you'll had gotten 2.

```
local.key = arrayFindNoCase(local.data, {name = "bar",value = 6 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's returning false because you're searching for:

```
{ value = 6 }
```

which is not an element of the array. The array has:

```
{ name = "bar", value = 6 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer is already here - as you found you cannot search a struct within an array via standard CF functions.

Here's a quick example of rolling your own if you want that specific functionality.

```
<cffunction name="arrayFindStructKey" returntype="numeric">
    <cfargument name="arr" type="array" required="true"> 
    <cfargument name="key" type="string" required="true">
    <cfargument name="val" type="string" required="true">

    <cfset var i = 0>

    <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(arguments.arr)#" index="i">
         <cfif isStruct(arguments.arr[i]) and structKeyExists(arguments.arr[i], arguments.key)>
              <cfif arguments.arr[i][arguments.key] eq arguments.val>
                  <cfreturn i>
              </cfif>
         </cfif>
    <\cfloop>

    <cfreturn 0> <!--- not found --->

</cffunction>
```